# multiple render text in jquery rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

For one action of user based on condition i want to render different
texts. So how do i achieve it through jquery?
For example:

A simple posting message application:

On post button i have a post method which has security checks and other
server side checks like :

```
if message_text.nil? or message_text.empty? or message_text.length > 140
      post_validation_check=true
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          render :text=> "<div id='outputDiv'><span
class='inputError'>Please enter message upto 140
characters</span></div>"
        }
        format.xml {
          render :xml=>hash_map_for_xml.to_xml(:root => "mb")
        }
      end
```

Normal post.js.erb is:

```
$("#div3").html("<%= escape_javascript render '/messages/timeline' %>");
```

which works if all is ok but how do i render messages like these when
user enters message greater than 140 characters? I have javascript
checks for them but i need these checks in case user enters it through
firebug skipping javascript.

When i see in firebug i do get the response but it is not painted on
browser as it doesnt know where to do it.

I feel i'm missing out soemthing very simple. Please let me know how can
this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

To bad you haven't posted you javascript check function but you probably have something like below code:

```
$("textarea").blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/controller/action',
        data: {message_text: $(this).val()},
        success: function(response) {
            $("#div3").html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Do you implemented the `success`